# Ajax failed registration do not echo result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, echo

I have a an ajax post method that if success will alert "account successfully created". my problem is when it's not created it should alert account already exists, But what the problem it still alert the same.

script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn-register").click(function(){
        var regaccount = $("#regaccount").val();
        var regpass = $("#regpass").val();

        if((regaccount == "") || (regpass == "")){
           alert("Information required!");
        }else {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: "regaccount="+regaccount+"&regpass="+regpass,
            success: function(data){    
                 alert("account successfully created!");
            },
            error:function(){
                 alert("account already exists");
            }
          });
        }
        $("#regaccount").val('');
        $("#regpass").val('');
        return false;  
    });
});
```

register.php

```
<?php 
    include 'function.php';
    session_start();
    ob_start(); 
    $userid = rand(100000, 999999);
        $regaccount = $_POST['regaccount'];
        $regpass = $_POST['regpass'];

        $regaccount = stripslashes($regaccount);
        $regpass = stripcslashes($regpass);
        $salt = "dctech2015ABcRXd";
        $regpass = md5($regpass) . $salt;
        $regpass = sha1($regpass);

        $con = new Functions();
        $con = $con->db;

        $stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$regaccount'");

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($count != 1){
            $con = new Functions();
            $con = $con->db;
            $status="Offline";
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username, password, status)VALUES(:userid, :account, :password, :status)");
            $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
            $stmt->bindValue(':account', $regaccount);
            $stmt->bindValue(':password', $regpass);
            $stmt->bindValue(':status', $status);
            $stmt->execute();
        }else{
            echo '<script>alert("account name already exists");</script>'; 
        }

    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Because you are not returning any error..you just echo message into register.php file.......alert(data);.........and check what is coming...I guess it is always comes under sucessfull

Comment: The `$.ajax()` error response is used to indicate an error from the header response on the server. It does **not** evaluate a conditional statement return from your PHP script. Instead, you should be returning a json object witha status or something that you can conditionally observe within the success function of the ajax callback.

Comment: Return message as per register.php.....I mean if record insrted then return   (echo 'success') and if record exist then return (echo 'exist)....then check into your javascript what comes under data and alert on the basis of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do following changes to make this work:

1) In your PHP code, do not write any alert.

2) Whether user exists in database or newly inserted, AJAX request will fetch only data. We have to handle the logic.

3) AJAX `error` method will be called only when AJAX request is failed (either request not sent or response status is not 200 OK).

4) In your case, `error` method will never be called if user already exists or even user is inserted as data is being correctly transferred from JavaScript to PHP.

```
if($count != 1){
  $con = new Functions();
  $con = $con->db;
  $status="Offline";
  $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username, password, status)VALUES(:userid, :account, :password, :status)");
  $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
  $stmt->bindValue(':account', $regaccount);
  $stmt->bindValue(':password', $regpass);
  $stmt->bindValue(':status', $status);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo 'success';
}
else{
  echo 'exists'; 
}
```

AND

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "register.php",
  data: "regaccount="+regaccount+"&regpass="+regpass,
  success: function(data){    
    if (data == 'success') {
      alert("account successfully created!");
    }
    else if (data == 'exists') {
      alert("account already exists");
    }
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("Unknown problem occured.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir @Pupil :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to prompt message into *AJAX* error section which is wrong. You need to handle both into success section.

The very simple example is, return `$count` and check that value if greater then 0 means record is exist.

Changes in *register.php* code:

```
if($count != 1){
    $con = new Functions();
    $con = $con->db;
    $status="Offline";
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_id, username, password, status)VALUES(:userid, :account, :password, :status)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid);
    $stmt->bindValue(':account', $regaccount);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $regpass);
    $stmt->bindValue(':status', $status);
    $stmt->execute();
}
echo $count;
```

I remove else part which is not require. And use `$count` for AJAX response.

And make correspond change into *AJAX* part also:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "register.php",
  data: "regaccount="+regaccount+"&regpass="+regpass,
  success: function(data){ 
        //If record exist...
      if(data > 0){
        alert("account name already exists");
      }
      else {
        alert("account successfully created!");
      }
  },
  error:function(){
       alert("There is some error, Please try after some time OR contact site admin.");
  }
});
```

Hope this is very easy to understand and help to other user also.